# Find $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}{\ln{(n^{15}+n+\ln{n})} \over \ln{(\sqrt{n^{22}+1772}+666n^6+13)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to figure out:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}{\ln{(n^{15}+n+\ln{n})} \over \ln{(\sqrt{n^{22}+1772}+666n^6+13)}}$$

So far I have tried the Stolz theorem. What looks promising at first, quickly ends in ${ln{1} \over ln{1}}$. Do you have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$
n^{15}+n+\ln n=n^{15}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{14}}+\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)
$$
so
$$
\ln(n^{15}+n+\ln n)=
15\ln n+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{14}}+\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)=
\ln n\left(15+\frac{1}{\ln n}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{14}}+\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)\right)
$$
Similarly,
$$
\ln{(\sqrt{n^{22}+1772}+666n^6+13)}=
\ln n\left(11+\frac{1}{\ln n}\ln\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1772}{n^{22}}}+
\frac{666}{n^5}+\frac{13}{n^{11}}\right)\right)
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{\ln(n^{15}+n+\ln n)}{\ln{(\sqrt{n^{22}+1772}+666n^6+13)}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{15+\frac{1}{\ln n}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{14}}+\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)}
{11+\ln\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1772}{n^{22}}}+
\frac{666}{n^5}+\frac{13}{n^{11}}\right)}
$$

---

More compactly, you can write
$$
n^{15}+n+\ln n=n^{15}f(n)\qquad
\sqrt{n^{22}+1772}+666n^6+13=n^{11}g(n)
$$
where
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)=1
\qquad\text{so}\qquad
\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(f(n))=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(g(n))=0
$$
(just write $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ as before).

Therefore
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{\ln(n^{15}+n+\ln n)}{\ln{(\sqrt{n^{22}+1772}+666n^6+13)}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{15\ln n+\ln(f(n))}{11\ln n+\ln(g(n))}
=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{15+\dfrac{\ln(f(n))}{\ln n}}{11+\dfrac{\ln(g(n))}{\ln n}}
$$
and

Answer (score 3):

Use *equivalents*:

- $n^{15}+n+\ln{n}\sim_\infty n^{15}$, hence $\ln (n^{15}+n+\ln{n})\sim_\infty 15\ln n$.
- $\sqrt{n^{22}+1772}+666n^6+13\sim_\infty n^{11} $, hence $\;\ln(\sqrt{n^{22}+1772}+666n^6+13)\sim_\infty11\ln n $.

Thus $$\frac{\ln (n^{15}+n+\ln{n})}{\ln(\sqrt{n^{22}+1772}+666n^6+13)}\sim_\infty\frac{15\ln n}{11\ln n}=\frac{15}{11}.$$

Answer (score 1):

As $n$ gets very large $n^{15} + n + \ln n \to n^{15}$ and $\sqrt{n^{22} + 1722} + 666n^6 + 16 \to n^{11}$

leaving us with $\frac {\ln n^{15}}{\ln n^{11}} =\frac {15 \ln n}{11\ln n} = \frac {15}{11}$

Comment: How do we justify the use of asymptotics, given that the expressions are contain in a $\ln$ expression?

Comment: Or is there a general theorem, for when we can do things like that?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\to$ here?

Comment: I am using  $\to$ to say "goes to" or "resembles."  I suppose it would be more formal to use "little o" notation.

Comment: If one does not give a precise meaning to $\to$, there is no mathematical proof here. Note furthermore that your use of $\to$ runs contrary to some nearly universal conventions.

Comment: I never intended to provide a precise proof.  I am just pointing the direction.

Comment: Why not give a precise proof when 1. obviously the OP is learning the subject and 2. it is so easy to provide one?

Answer (score 1):

As $n\to +\infty$ we can approximate:

$$\ln(n^{15} + n + \ln(n)) \approx \ln(n^{15}) = 15\ln(n)$$

and

$$\ln(\sqrt{n^{22} + 1772} + 666n^6 + 13) \approx \ln(\sqrt{n^{22}} + 666n^6) \approx \ln(n^{11} + 666n^6) \approx \ln(n^{11}) = 11\ln(n)$$

Hence we get

$$\frac{15\ln(n)}{11\ln(n)} = \frac{15}{11}$$

Comment: If one does not give a precise meaning to $\approx$, there is no mathematical proof here.

Comment: @Did We theoretical physicists don't need the "mathematical proof". It works, so it's enough. :D :D 

Anyway, let me know if I shall edit it with the big O little O symbols. Unless someone already did.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If

- $u_n>0\;,\;v_n>0$
- $u_n\sim v_n \;\;(n\to+\infty)$
- $ \lim_{n\to+\infty}u_n\neq 1$

then

$$\ln(u_n)\sim \ln(v_n)\;\;(n\to +\infty).$$

with this, your limit is $$\color{green}{ \frac{15}{11}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $n\sim n+5$ as $n\to \infty.$ Does that imply $e^{n} \sim e^{n+5}?$ Clearly not. (Here $\sim$ means the ratio $\to 1.$) So we need to be careful with our asymptotics.

Suppose $a_n,b_n \to \infty$ and $a_n\sim c_n, b_n\sim d_n.$ Then $\lim\, (\ln a_n)/(\ln b_n) = \lim\, (\ln c_n)/(\ln d_n),$ provided the latter limit exists.

Proof: For large $n,$ $a_n = c_n(a_n/c_n), b_n = d_n(b_n/d_n).$ Thus

$$\frac{\ln a_n}{\ln b_n} =\frac{\ln c_n + \ln (a_n/c_n) }{\ln d_n + \ln (b_n/d_n)}.$$

Since $a_n/c_n,b_n/d_n \to 1,$  $\ln (a_n/c_n),\ln (b_n/d_n) \to 0.$ So dividing the top and bottom of the last fraction by $\ln d_n$ shows it has limit equal to $\lim\, (\ln c_n)/(\ln d_n).$

This will give a simple solution to the given problem.